# Count elements if in both arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Is there any possibility to compare two arrays without two loops?
I have two arrays with Strings and need to count the number of equal elements. (The length of the arrays can be different)

Comment: If you want/need to compare all the elements from an array with all the elements from another array, then you need two loops (or recursive methods that can be replaced by loops). Alternatively, you may use a `Map<String, Integer>` to hold the `String`s and a counter per entry.

Comment: Nope. Unless they're equal size, two loops is a must.

Comment: Supposing that all elements are unique in each array, add all elements to a Set then work with the size of the Set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like this

```
String[] a ={"A","B"};
String[] b={"A","B","C"};
List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(a));
list.retainAll(Arrays.asList(b));
System.out.println(list);
System.out.println("equal elements:"+list.size());
```

**output**

```
[A, B]
equal elements:2
```

Answer (score 3):

Supposing that all elements are unique in each array :

```
String[] a ={"A","B", "E"};
String[] b={"A","B","C", "D", "E"};

Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.addAll(Arrays.asList(a));
set.addAll(Arrays.asList(b));

System.out.println("nb of equal elements "+ (a.length + b.length - set.size()));
```

If the elements are not unique in each array, create an intermediate set for both arrays.

Comment: I like this idea. Using `Set` to tackle this issue provides a very elegant solution. +1.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Arrays.asList(...).contains(...)` and for each "`true`" result increment a counter (`cont++`);

Hope it helps!

Comment: I understood that he doesn't want to use to loops explicitly

Answer (score 0):

Basically, no. You have to use at least two nested loops (`for`, `while`, `do-while`) or another techniques like recursive methods that mimics the loops, but in the end you will use two. Even if you use `List#contains` (as noted in [RafaRomero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20614949/1065197)) you're using two nested loops, not explicitly but they're there.

Another option may be using `Set<String>` to store the `String`s and if the element is already in the `Set` then your counter will add 1 value. Note that this alternative will use two **not nested** loops:

```
public int countEqualElements(String[] yourFirstStringArray, String[] yourSecondStringArray) {
    Set<String> mainData = new HashSet<String>();
    int counter = 0;
    for (String string : yourFirstStringArray) {
        mainData.add(string);
    }
    for (String string : yourSecondStringArray) {
        if (!mainData.add(string)) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using set method in Collection (unique values)

```
    String[] arrayA = new String[] {"A", "B", "C"};
    String[] arrayB = new String[] { "B", "C", "D"};
    Set<String> setA= new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(arrayA));
    Set<String> setB= new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(arrayB));
    setA.retainAll(setB);
    System.out.println(setA.size());
```